# Handle EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in JNI with java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm new to JNI. I'm trying exception handling in Cpp. For the class not found exception I'm able to handle the exception as below

```
     jclass some=env->FindClass("java/some/class");   
     jboolean flag = env->ExceptionCheck();
       if (flag) {
         env->ExceptionClear();
         printf("Exception in native method");
         jclass jcls =env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassNotFoundException");
         env->ThrowNew(jcls, "Exception in Native Method");
       }
```

But for methodid if I give the wrong methodName it doesn't throws exception.

```
    jmethodID mId = env->GetMethodID( someClass, "wrongmethodName", "()V");
    jboolean flag = env->ExceptionCheck();
           if (flag) {
             env->ExceptionClear();
             printf("Exception in native method");
             jclass jcls =env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
             env->ThrowNew(jcls, "Exception in Native Method");
           }
```

Instead JVM crashes and generates log file as hs_err_pidxxx.txt containing the following

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x63c7e45b, pid=30652, tid=0x00009098
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [jvm.dll+0xde45b]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x193d7800):  JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-2" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=37016, stack(0x19cb0000,0x19d00000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

    Registers:
    EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x193d7940, ECX=0x193d7800, EDX=0x0000062d
    ESP=0x19cff040, EBP=0x19cff088, ESI=0x193d7800, EDI=0x00000000
    EIP=0x63c7e45b, EFLAGS=0x00010246

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x19cff040)
    0x19cff040:   193d7800 18dd0880 18dd0888 63e87cf4
    0x19cff050:   176397f0 193d7800 00000000 0000000e
    0x19cff060:   19cfefdc 19cff0d4 0000000e 193d7800
    0x19cff070:   00000007 18dd0888 193d7800 17e1cbc4
    0x19cff080:   0000062d 63e87bc8 19cff0b8 6af82dd8
    0x19cff090:   193d7940 18a00b14 00000000 19cff0cc
    0x19cff0a0:   74ca2fcb 74cae600 19cff0cc 19cff0cc
    0x19cff0b0:   00000000 19cff0c8 19cff238 6af81b74 

    Instructions: (pc=0x63c7e45b)
    0x63c7e43b:   f2 ff 83 c4 08 83 7e 04 00 89 75 f0 c7 45 f4 00
    0x63c7e44b:   00 00 00 74 08 8d 4d f0 e8 08 c3 0c 00 8b 7d 10
    0x63c7e45b:   8b 07 c7 45 e0 04 00 00 00 8b 40 04 0f b7 48 1c
    0x63c7e46b:   8b 50 08 8b 44 8a 2c 50 8d 4d c4 e8 b5 5e 09 00 


    Register to memory mapping:

    EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
    EBX=0x193d7940 is an unknown value
    ECX=0x193d7800 is a thread
    EDX=0x0000062d is an unknown value
    ESP=0x19cff040 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x193d7800
    EBP=0x19cff088 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x193d7800
    ESI=0x193d7800 is a thread
    EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


    Stack: [0x19cb0000,0x19d00000],  sp=0x19cff040,  free space=316k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [jvm.dll+0xde45b]
    C  [crud.dll+0x2dd8]
    C  [crud.dll+0x1b74]
    j  NativeService.view(LUser;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;+0
```

Can anyone please suggest me a way to handle the exception instead of JVM crash and generation of error log. A bunch of thanks.

Comment: Are you returning immediately after calling `ThrowNew()`?  The posted code isn't complete.   `ThrowNew()` does not cause your JNI function to return.

Comment: I found the error. Thank you for your comment @Andrew Henle